# Fem!Harry Potter married to Voldemort

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

I remember snippets of the story.

Like Dumbledore telling Fem!Harry (don't know if the name changes) that Voldemort/Tom Riddle (who is no longer snake-faced) offered a ceasefire in return for her signing a marriage/bonding contact and moving in with him. And her begging Dumbledore not to tell Remus and Sirius about it and pretend he's training her for the war.

Then I think she keeps fighting with Riddle and he ends up raping her (she's a virgin) then gives her a gold chain portkey or something which he uses to tie her up.

And there is some old guy called Samson, I think he's Riddle's friend or counselor and they keep sparring a lot. And he starts teaching "Harry" how to control and use her anger in magic.

Comment: "Fem!Harry" = female Harry right? Just to clarify, since not everyone is familiar with fanfic terminology.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! These might help you to improve your question; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [How to ask a good (Fanfic) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11922/how-to-ask-a-good-fanfic-story-id-question)

Comment: Wouldn't that be "Harriette" rather than "Harry?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called the "Ichor Series" by the author Nocturnememory, starting with the first part "Charity, Thou Art a Lie".  According to their tumblr, they deleted it off Ao3 because a bunch of people flame reviewed.

The part OP is referring to starts from Part III of the series, "Bittersweet Undefeated Creature".  Unfortunately, I can't recall which chapter(s) exactly she gets the necklace because it's been deleted.

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE. It would help the OP if you could also elaborate on which parts of the *Ichor Series* you think matches his own description.

Comment: @Sharona could you please tell me the name of the second part..

Comment: @Miranitta - Part II is called "Yes, I have a thousand tongues".